# TikZ plots height and subfloats vertical alignment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, vertical-alignment, subfloats

I'm using this code to put two TikZ figures on one row:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\tikzset{declare function={gauss(\x,\y,\z)=
1/(\z*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((\x-\y)^2)/(2*\z^2));}}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
 \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
   \centering
   \include{./figures/HypothesisTestingTwoTailed}
   \caption{two-tailed test}
   \label{fig:OneAndTwoTailedTests-Two}
  \end{subfigure}
  \quad
  \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
   \centering
   \include{./figures/HypothesisTestingOneTailed}
   \caption{one-tailed test}
   \label{fig:OneAndTwoTailedTests-One}
  \end{subfigure}\\
  \caption{One- and two-tailed tests}
  \label{fig:OneAndTwoTailedTests}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

This is one of the pictures:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[%
   no markers,
   domain=-3:3,
   height=4cm, width=7cm,
   samples=61, smooth,
   axis x line=bottom,
   axis y line=none,
   xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
   clip=false,
   enlargelimits=upper
  ]

  \node [coordinate] at (axis cs:0,0) (origin) {};
  \node [coordinate] at (axis cs:-2.5,0) (alphaleft) {};
  \node [coordinate] at (axis cs:2.5,0) (alpharight) {};

  \node[coordinate] (zleft)  at (axis cs:-2,{gauss(-2,0,1)}) {};
  \draw (axis cs:-2,0) -- (zleft);

  \node[coordinate] (zright) at (axis cs:2,{gauss(2,0,1)}) {};
  \draw (axis cs:2,0) -- (zright);

  \addplot [thick] {gauss(x,0,1)};

  \node[coordinate] (top) at (axis cs:0,{gauss(0,0,1)}) {};
  \draw [dashed] (axis cs:0,0) -- (top);

  \node [below = 1mm of origin] {$\mu$};
  \node [below = 1mm of alphaleft, anchor=north] {$\alpha/2$};
  \node [below = 1mm of alpharight, anchor=north] {$\alpha/2$};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The only difference should be that in the left picture there is "a/2", which is higher than "a" because of the "/".

I want to have the two horizontal axes aligned. Rather than using alignment options of subfloats, I'd prefer to work on the picture size instead. I'm looking for a way to set the padding around (specifically, below) the plot, so that it is the same for both pictures, and this would cause them to be correctly aligned. I'm going to add a third picture, and some stuff below two of them, so I think that setting padding would be the best way to have the right alignment. Is that possible?

Thank you!

Comment: You could just add a `\vphantom{\alpha/2}` before `\alpha` in the second plot. Of course, you could also use group plots.

Comment: Thank you! However I still need to set an exact value for the padding, because I'm going to make three new plots, with other stuff below two of them, in different positions, so `\vpanthom` wouldn't work. I'll take a look to group plots, is that a feature of pgfplots?

Comment: Yes, group plots is a feature of pgfplots. You should also make your plot compilable, `flat.sty` seems not to be a standard package, and you need to add `\usepackage{subcaption}` to the preamble.

Comment: Whops... that should have been `flOat` :-D (I'm a disaster with MWEs). What do you mean by making the plot compilable?

Comment: I guess that the main problem is that you set the nodes by hand and not with xtick labels.

Comment: It could be, in the picture I used as example, but I need to do that by hand because I'm going to add labels on a second and a third row, other labels splitted on two rows, and other text... I took a look at groupplots and I think that they'll do the work

Comment: @marmot I tried to use `groupplot` with the same parameters I used with `axis`. Everything works fine except that the `smooth` key is not recognized. Do you know why? EDIT: solved with `/tikz/smooth`